# Is there a pandas function that can read multiple excel sheets but with only sheet1 having a header

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code to read multiple sheets.

```
df = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xls',sheet_name=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'])
```

But only sheet1 has a header. Sheet2 and sheet3 have no header.

Comment: are all the headers the same for each sheet? if so, why dont you just set them manually and declare them after the fact?

Comment: Yes, all headers are the same for each sheet. Yes, i did add them manually but some workbook have more than 20+ sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the first sheet with header and the remaining sheets without. Apply the first sheet's column header to the remaining sheets and concatenate the lot. Since dict values enumerate in insertion order, the sheet read order should be the same. Alternately you could sort by sheet name or other criteria.

```
import pandas as pd
sheets = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xls',sheet_name=['Sheet1'])
columns = sheets["Sheet1"].columns
sheets.update(pd.read_excel('excelfile.xls', header=None,
    sheet_name=['Sheet2','Sheet3']))
for sheet in sheets.values():
    sheet.columns = columns
df = pd.concat(sheets.values())
print(df)
```

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. read first df with header
2. read second df2 without header
3. add header to df2

df2.columns = ['A', 'B']

4. append df2 to df1

df.append(df2)

Comment: Thank you for helping.